# Haskell Maybe Int to Int

Tags: haskell, int, type-conversion, option-type

I have a function where `n` needs to be an `Int` but is a `Maybe Int`; how could I convert this? I'm aware that this has been asked before, but I don't understand the answer.

```
where n = case elemIndex column header of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just n  -> n
```

Comment: Depends on how you would like to represent `Nothing` value in `Integer` type. This seems to be an index operation so you may try like `Nothing -> -1`

Comment: This strictly depends on what you actually are trying to achieve. What do you need to happen when the column is not present in the header? If that should never happen, you can raise a runtime error using `... Nothing -> error "column not found!?"`. If I had to guess, I'd say that there is a problem above the `where`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`, but you have to supply a default value that will be used in case the value is `Nothing`:

```
*Q46363709> :m +Data.Maybe
*Q46363709 Data.Maybe> fromMaybe 0 (Just 42)
42
*Q46363709 Data.Maybe> fromMaybe 0 Nothing
0
```

The `Maybe` type, however, is a `Functor`, so often, instead of always supplying default values, you can `fmap` the result of calling your function. Assuming that your function `foo` has the type `Int -> String`, you can do this:

```
*Q46363709> fmap foo $ Just 42
Just "42"
```

Often, while you may not have a good default value for the input (i.e. no good default `Int`), you may have a suitable default value for the output. In this case, assuming that `""` (the empty `String`) is a good default output value, you could use `fromMaybe` on the output instead of the input:

```
*Q46363709 Data.Maybe> fromMaybe "" $ fmap foo $ Just 42
"42"
*Q46363709 Data.Maybe> fromMaybe "" $ fmap foo $ Nothing
""
```

As you can see, when the input is `Just 42`, the output is `"42"`, but when the input is `Nothing`, then the output is `""`.

(BTW, I used `show` for `foo`, as you can tell...)

Answer (score 1):

This can't work: On the right side of the `->` you have one time a `Nothing` and the next time an `Int`. For this to work, you need to provide a default value in case of `Nothing` (e.g. -1)

Comment: Yes, but I suspect a better solution would be to not compute any `n` at all in the `Nothing` case – this should probably be handled with an entirely different clause in the enclosing function.